# how to handle subprocess.Popen output in both Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

I have a simple function that checks if a program is running and returns a boolean as appropriate. It does this by checking the output of the command `ps -A` using the module `subprocess`. I'm trying to get this function to work in both Python 2 and Python 3 but am encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How should the function be changed such that it can work in *both* Python 2 and Python 3?

```
import subprocess

def running(program):
    results = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ps", "-A"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE
    ).communicate()[0].split("\n")
    matches_current = [
        line for line in results if program in line and "defunct" not in line
    ]
    if matches_current:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

EDIT: Following some guidance by @Josh, I've changed the newline string delimiter to bytecode, however I'm still encountering a similar problem:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> def running(program):
...     results = subprocess.Popen(
...         ["ps", "-A"],
...         stdout = subprocess.PIPE
...     ).communicate()[0].split(b"\n")
...     matches_current = [
...         line for line in results if program in line and "defunct" not in line
...     ]
...     if matches_current:
...         return True
...     else:
...         return False
... 
>>> running("top")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in running
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <listcomp>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Btw, usually the full traceback is much more useful than just the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bytestrings like `b"\n"` instead of just plain `"\n"`, and also use `program.encode()` instead of `program` (assuming you're being passed a string):

```
results = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ps", "-A"],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
).communicate()[0].split(b"\n")
matches_current = [
    line for line in results if program.encode() in line and b"defunct" not in line
]
```

This is because in Python 3, `subprocess.Popen.communicate` returns bytes rather than a string by default. In Python 2.6+, `b"\n" == "\n"`, so you shouldn't have any problems there.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance on this. I've made the change you suggested, but I seem to be still encountering a similar problem. I've edited my post to add what I'm seeing.

Comment: @BlandCorporation ah, you'll probably also need `b"defunct"` instead of `"defunct"` in the list comprehension, and you may need `program.encode()` instead of just `program`.

Comment: Aye, changing `"defunct"` to `b"defunct"` and adding `program = str.encode(program)` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but I've found a simpler way that works both in Python 2 and 3: add `.decode()` after `communicate()[0]`:

```
results = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ps", "-A"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE
    ).communicate()[0].decode().split("\n")
```

So you don't have to add `b`'s before every string literal or `encode()` to string variables in your code. As a bonus, `results` will become an Unicode string.

PS. In my case I had `subprocess.check_output()` and appending `.decode()` also worked as expected.

EDIT: probably it is better to specify encoding, like `decode('utf-8')` just in case.

Answer (score 2):

`universal_newlines=True` produces strings instead of bytes.

```
results = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ps", "-A"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True
    ).communicate()[0].split("\n")
```

Using iterator

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ps", "-A"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True
    )
for result in p.stdin:
    print(result.strip())
```